# Mac Mini as a DVR

Tags: mac, mac-mini, dvr

I have my Mac Mini attached to my HD LCD TV. Is there any hardware/software available for me to use my Mac mini as a DVR/PVR that has similar functionality to Tivo. The Mac mini's form factor is small enough to fit in my living room entertainment center and using it would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an article about that very subject on [The Unofficial Apple Weblog](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/08/21/tuaw-guide-setting-up-the-ultimate-mac-mini-home-theater/) not too long ago.